# Xamarin.Forms Login form need double tap to submit form when soft Keyboard is present

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Login screen is not behaving as I would expect, the first tap on the signin button only dismisses the soft keyboard, no event is fired by the button.
So to login, the user would have to app once more the login button.

This doesn't seems right to me, but I'm trying to figure out if this is the expected behavior and maybe I should dismiss the keyboard manually. Or if this should be dismissed and passed the event along by Forms.

Here is a repo with a sample of the problem: https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/ScrollLoginBug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SignIn Button is blocked by the keyboard. The only way for the user to tap the SignIn Button is to dismiss the keyboard, then tap the button.

If you describe the UI that you're trying to implement, I'll edit my answer and provide some code.

[image]
[image]

## Update

The reason user has to click twice after entering the password to tap the SignIn Button is because you have a `Grid` nested inside of your `StackLayout`. After removing the `Grid`, the user is able

## Original ScrollLoginTestPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="ScrollLoginTest.ScrollLoginTestPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollLoginTest">
    <ContentPage.Content BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}">
        <ScrollView x:Name="LoginScrollView" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="40">
                <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Entry x:Name="Server"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_Server"
                           Keyboard="Url"
                           Placeholder="Server"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="UserName"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_UserName"
                           Keyboard="Email"
                           Placeholder="UserName"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="Password"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.Column="0"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_Password"
                           IsPassword="true"
                           Placeholder="Password"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                </Grid>
                <Grid VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".6*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width=".20*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="LoginButton"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            AutomationId="LoginView_SignIn"
                            Style="{DynamicResource blueButton}"
                            Text="SignIn" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

## Updated ScrollLoginTestPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage x:Class="ScrollLoginTest.ScrollLoginTestPage"
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScrollLoginTest;assembly=ScrollLoginTest">
    <ContentPage.Content BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}">
        <ScrollView x:Name="LoginScrollView" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource defaultBackgroundColor}">
            <StackLayout Padding="40">
                    <Entry x:Name="Server"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_Server"
                           Keyboard="Url"
                           Placeholder="Server"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="UserName"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_UserName"
                           Keyboard="Email"
                           Placeholder="UserName"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                    <Entry x:Name="Password"
                           VerticalOptions="End"
                           AutomationId="LoginView_Password"
                           IsPassword="true"
                           Placeholder="Password"
                           Style="{DynamicResource regularEntry}" />
                 <Button x:Name="LoginButton"
                            AutomationId="LoginView_SignIn"
                            Style="{DynamicResource blueButton}"
                            Text="SignIn" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

I opened a Pull Request for your solution in GitHub: https://github.com/GiusepeCasagrande/ScrollLoginBug/pull/1

Comment: Hi @brandon-minnick, actually you don't need to dismiss the keyboard. If you scroll the view you can tap the button. I can add a ScrollTo into the repo and make the button visible. But won't change the results.

Comment: What is your goal with the Login Page? Would you like the button to be always visible? Would you like the keyboard return button to trigger the SignIn Button when the user finishes entering in the password?

Comment: Ok, I have made a small change in the project, this may be clearer now. What I want is that the user don't have to tap twice in the login button to login. To reproduce the problem: fill something in the user, tap login and fill something in the password (the page will scroll now) and try tapping the button.

Comment: Hey @Giusepe! I updated my answer to explain why the user needed to tap twice to tap the SignIn button. I also opened a Pull Request on your GitHub repo that includes an extra feature that allows the user to tap the keyboard return button in-lieu of tapping the SignIn button. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Hey @brandon-minnick! First let me thank you for all the support so far, you have been amazing :) Now, I have made an update in the repo and seems that the problem isn't the Grid, but the scroll somehow. Pull, run it on simulator with the soft keyboard, focus on any field, scroll and try to tap the button. It will scroll back and not register the tap

Comment: Hey @Giusepe, thank you for the kind words! You're experiencing the expected behavior of a ScrollView. Xamarin.Forms is scrolling the UI up for you automatically so that the keyboard doesn't block the Entry. When you tap on the SignIn Button while the keyboard is visible, Xamarin.Forms first scrolls the UI back down. There are a couple of work-arounds for this: 1. Don't use a ScrollView to allow the user to see the SignIn Button when they are unable to tap it; 2. Use the Custom Return Entry I added in the GitHub Pull-Request to allow the user to login after entering their password.

Comment: Thank you again @brandom-minnick.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered in Xamarin Forum. This is a bug in Xamarin Button's focus/unfocus event in iOS. 
Bug Report can be found in: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57377

The Work-around solution is using "TapGestureRecognizer" instead of Button Click. Replace you Button with code below will fix your problem:

```
<Frame x:Name="SendButton" HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="White">
    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="SendClicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
```

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69196/xamarin-forms-ios-button-click-event-is-not-firing-when-the-keyboard-is-open